# Unable to retrieve data from SQLite database iOS6.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, ios6

When i run build ios5.0  or less then Sqlite response correct and retrieve data its work fine but when run on ios6.0  i am trying to fetch data from my.sqlite database but it is not executing my if case. It always enters in else condition. What wrong thing i am doing? I am not able to execute my if case i.e. `if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlQuerry, -1, &querryStatement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK).`

for reference  check this code .

```
NSLog(@"sqlite3_prepare_v2 = %d SQLITE_OK %d ",sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite, [strQuery UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, nil),SQLITE_OK);

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite, [strQuery UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSLog(@"sqlite3_step = %d SQLITE_ROW %d ",sqlite3_step(compiledStatement),SQLITE_ROW);
        while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement)==SQLITE_ROW)
        {           if(sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2) != nil)
                modelObj.Name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];

        }
    }
    else
    {

    }
```

On iOS6.0 log Print

```
 sqlite3_prepare_v2 = 1 SQLITE_OK 0   
 sqlite3_step = 21 SQLITE_ROW 100
```

On iOS5.0 log Print

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2 = 0 SQLITE_OK 0  
sqlite3_step = 100 SQLITE_ROW 100
```

Comment: based on your provided output it doesn't look as if it's entering the else case at all - in both iOS5 and iOS6 we see both log messages.

Comment: See this answer, you might have the same problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/6749033/73429

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place in the else this, so we can see the error that is resulting..

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite, [strQuery UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
{

    NSLog(@"sqlite3_step = %d SQLITE_ROW %d ",sqlite3_step(compiledStatement),SQLITE_ROW);
    while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement)==SQLITE_ROW)
    {           if(sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2) != nil)
        modelObj.Name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];

    }
}
else{
    //error
    NSLog(@"Failed to open database. Error: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete your app from your device (Or simulator) then clean & build

Comment: so many time delete app from device also simulator clean build and also try quit xcode. but not executing data from sqlite in ios6.0

Comment: the Query is :  SELECT * FROM Sites ORDER BY Title ASC

Comment: Did you try to delete the application from simulator under iOS6 and not under iOS5 ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but regarding this:
**NULL** is a **void ***, **nil** is an **id**

So if you can change this:

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite, [strQuery UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
```

Whit this:

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite, [strQuery UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
```

I just change nil with NULL. Again not 100% sure but only this I see in your code. I always use NULL :)

Hope this help...